# Not able to install mysql-community-server on Amazon linux 2

Tags: mysql, amazon-linux-2

When ever I am trying the command

`sudo yum install mysql-community-server`

I am getting the following error

```
The GPG keys listed for the "MySQL 8.0 Community Server" repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package. The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction. You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
```

Answer (score 3):

Running the following command solves it!

`sudo rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022`

After this need to run the command again

`sudo yum install mysql-community-server`